# Piping credential into Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell

- PowerShell 5.1.17763.592 / Windows Server 2019 Version 1809 (build 17763.737)

I am trying to download a file with the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet. The file is protected by HTTP basic auth. Doing a two-step like this works:

```
PS E:\> $cred = Get-Credential

cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Credential
PS E:\> Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://example.com/foo.zip -Credential $cred -OutFile $env:TEMP\foo.zip
```

Trying to pipe in the credential so I can do it in a one-liner fails:

```
PS E:\> Get-Credential | Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://example.com/foo.zip -Credential $_ -OutFile $env:TEMP\foo.zip

cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Credential
Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.
At line:1 char:18
+ ... redential | Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://example.com/foo.z ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ProtocolViolationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Net.ProtocolViolationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

I've googled the error but the only thing I can find is [Invoke-WebRequest using Get method doesn't allow content-body](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2054), but if that's the root cause I don't understand why the two-liner would work. I suspect I've misunderstood how `$_` is evaluated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fake a "one-liner" with semicolons used to separate statements like this:

```
$cred = Get-Credential ; Invoke-WebRequest -Credential $cred -Uri http://example.com/foo.zip -OutFile $env:TEMP\foo.zip
```

If security isn't an issue you can create the credential without prompts:

```
$User = "whatever"
$Pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "plaintextpassword" -Force -AsPlainText
$Cred = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $User, $Pass
Invoke-WebRequest -Credential $Cred -Uri http://example.com/foo.zip -OutFile $env:TEMP\foo.zip
```

As noted, the comment by JosefZ works as well and includes the reason why you can't just pipeline the `Get-Credential` object into `Invoke-Webrequest` by itself:

> $_ is a pipeline object however -Credential parameter does not accept
>   pipeline input. Use e.g.
>
> ```
> Get-Credential | ForEach-Object {Invoke-WebRequest -Credential $_ -Uri …}
> ```